# How do I escape mustache syntax?

Tags: mustache

Assuming I have some mustache template code like this:

```
{{#list}}
  <p>
  This should be replaced: {{name}}
  This is not replaced: \{{example}}   <== this doesn't work, just for illustration
  </p>
{{/list}}
```

I'd like the output to look something like:

```
<p>
This should be replaced: Bob
This is not replaced: {{example}}
</p>
```

How do I escape syntax that looks like mustache code so that it is rendered as literal `{{` and `}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in escaping mechanism (as far as I know), but you could temporarily change the tag delimiter:

```
{{#list}}
  <p>
  This should be replaced: {{name}}
  This is not replaced: {{=<% %>=}}{{example}}<%={{ }}=%>
  </p>
{{/list}}
```

Or use HTML escapes:

```
This is not replaced: &#123;&#123;example&#125;&#125;
```

Comment: first solution works even if you have to escape a single `{` in front of a `{{`: `{{=<% %>=}}{<%={{ }}=%>{{example}}`